# Swagger doc for custom endpoint

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

For my project, I created a entity Category. Its repository class is extending the NestedTreeRepository from the resp. STOF-Extension. I implemented a custom endpoint to move a category within the tree. The functionality is working fine, but I'm struggling with the swagger documentation.

I followed the instructions in the api platform documentation, but with no success.

App\Entity\Cagegory:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use \DateTime;
use \DateTimeInterface;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"tree"}},
 *     "item_operations"={
 *         "get"={"method"="GET"},
 *         "put"={"method"="PUT"},
 *         "delete"={"method"="DELETE"},
 *         "moveCategory"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "route_name"="category_move",
 *             "swagger_context" = {
 *                 "parameters" = {
 *                     {
 *                         "name" = "id",
 *                         "in" = "path",
 *                         "required" = "true",
 *                         "type" = "integer"
 *                     },
 *                     {
 *                         "name" = "amount",
 *                         "in" = "path",
 *                         "required" = "true",
 *                         "type" = "integer"
 *                     }
 *                 },
 *                 "responses" = {
 *                     "200" = {
 *                         "description" = "The category has been moved"
 *                     }
 *                 }
 *             }
 *         }
 *      }
 * })
 *
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 * use repository for handy tree functions
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
 */
class Category
...
```

config/routes.yaml:

```
category_move:
    path: /api/categories/{id}/move/{amount}
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: App\Controller\CategoryController::move
        _api_resource_class: App\Entity\Category
        _api_item_operation_name: moveCategory
```

When I reload the swagger page, it still shows the standard operations, but not my custom endpoint.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you follow wrong the doc, you should use "itemOperations". This will help you: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers

Comment: Thanks. Tried that as well, but still does not work.

Comment: In my app i also got an use case similar to you. Maybe this will help you : https://pastebin.com/VidpN3N5

Comment: I removed the attributes block from the annotation and it worked. Thanks a lot!